# Reverse engineering PCB

Tags: pcb, hardware, reverse-engineering

I am trying to obtain the layout and eventually netlist/schematic for PCBs I have.

I am wondering what others have tried to understand how a piece of hardware works, obtain a reference design, and what components are placed on the board.

I have seen AI/ML techniques being used (object detection, etc)

Comment: What you propose is far more complicated than you probably think it is. The machine vision alone could be the subject of a Ph.D. dissertation, not to mention all the other parts of it. And *then* you get to multilayer boards, where lots of wiring is just not visible at all.

Comment: If you can’t see it, you’ll have to probe for it. So this approach is not useable beyond 2 layers.

Comment: You can iteratively image and then abrade or dissolve layers to reconstruct multilayer boards. Segmenting traces and converting that to a netlist is complex however.

Comment: _"I am trying to obtain the layout and eventually netlist/schematic for PCBs I have"_ - Why?

Answer (score 1):

It is somewhat of a strange question.

Generally speaking one needs intense  science and study to understand natural phenomenon which is hidden from us since when we were new on this earth. Point being that there isn't any crib sheet for nature so we use scientific method to "reverse engineer" what nature has designed  or, depending on your personal beliefs , possibly by a sentient deity.

PCBs aren't a hidden secret of the universe, they were designed
by intelligent humans , using standard techniques and approaches of their field . Likely in conference and collaboration with other experts and humans in their field. It is much easier to hire those people to help you than to try to reverse engineer their domain knowledge.

This is because a professional working in the industry would generally be able to "read" a competitors pcb and not require reverse engineering techniques to understand. It is easy to see ,ok that's the mcu, that's a power supply, here is signal conditioning for some sensor, here is some ddr memory, etc.

Intensive reverse engineering of the kind you are describing  is a very dramatic type of activity. Generally it is easier and cheaper to go and buy that "crib sheet", either by licensing, purchasing, or stealing the design materials them selves or even just hiring the original designers. For most commercial application there is very little incentive to truly reverse engineer, most companies would not have the patience for that activity and most professional electrical engineers will happily spend their entire careers making good moneys and never be asked to reverse engineer a design besides a cursory analysis .

Intensive reverse engineering techniques are applicable in certain, specific situations, and employed on case by case basis under direction of an expert designer , they do this either because someone physically cannot obtain design materials directly or otherwise is not willing to do it but at the same time are not willing to simply redesign from scratch.

Because the market for this is activity is limited and the tools are very niche, the tools available carry a heavy premiums, in cost and expertise needed.

In other words there is no generally applicable reverse engineering process , but there are countless of useful techniques that would be useful as well in this process.

For example , I have had PCB imaged using scanning  electron microscopy to confirm that the traces on each layer  matched the files we sent to the manufacturer and that the layers were stacked up in the correct order, this technique could also be used to reverse engineer the traces of the PCB.